# Acusport Datafeed solution

Tags: xml, wordpress, datafeed

Can you give me an idea how to import datafeed XML format to WordPress WooCommerce? They gave me these following XML files as a testing:

1. ItemAvailability_example.xml
2. ItemCatDesc_example.xml
3. ItemDelete_example.xml
4. ItemPrice_example.xml
5. ItemUpsert_example.xml
6. Order_cXML_example.xml
7. OrderAck_example.xml
8. OrderASN_example.xml

Actually, I installed WP all Import plugin and I watched the tutorial on it. But the difference is, they have 1 XML file containing all product details but not like those files above.

I hope you get it what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout https://www.channelape.com/overview/apps/woocommerce/acusport/. Can probably save you a huge headache

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, that isn't really possible the way you are trying. They expect you to create your own database and process each of those files as multiples of each type come over per day.

I have experience with this feed and will comment above on the solution we came up with if interested in chatting more.